# Define and use a string constant in C

Tags: c, string

I have code that uses multiple different strings in the code, like "my-app/123" and "my-app/#". Sometimes it's also used for further formatting (include other variables with `%` placeholders). Now I need to make this prefix more configurable by adding a `#define` statement for the string prefix. It then looks like this:

```c
#define MQTT_TOPIC "my-app"
```

But how can I use it without writing several lines of code and allocating memory for every usage? I've tried this but the compiler doesn't understand what I want:

```c
esp_mqtt_client_subscribe(client, MQTT_TOPIC + "/#", 0)
```

Strings are so complicated in C. The compiler should be able to resolve all of this because it's a preprocessor symbol, not a runtime string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `MQTT_TOPIC + "/#"` to `MQTT_TOPIC "/#"`. During compilation, adjacent string literals are concatenated.